# Solution of linear DE (What is my mistake )

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\phi$ be the solution of $ y' + iy = x$ such that $ \phi (0) =2$. Find $\phi(x)$.

My approach : 
$(e^{ix} \phi)' = xe^{ix}$
so now $e^{ix} \phi -2 = \int_0^x \! te^{it} \, \mathrm{d}t. $

so

$e^{ix} \phi -2 = -ixe^{ix} + e^{ix} -1 $

and solved further to get

$\phi = (1-ix) + e^{-ix}$

Am i making any mistake here ?
The correct answer given is

$\phi(x) = ix$

and is not matching with my answer

Comment: Not sure how $\phi(x)=ix$ is even a solution since $\phi(0) = 0 \neq 2$.

Comment: $\phi(x)=ix$ clearly is not the solution, since $\phi'(x) = i$ and $\phi'(x) + i\phi(x) = i + i\cdot ix = i-x \neq x$. Also, $\phi(0)=0\neq2$

Comment: SO should i assume my approach is correct and the answer in the book is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. For $\phi(x) = 1-ix+e^{-ix}$, you have $\phi'(x) = -i-ue^{-ix}$, meaning that 
$$\phi'(x) + i\phi(x) = -i-ie^{-ix} + i + x + ie^{-ix} = x,$$
so $\phi$ solves your equation. It is also true that $\phi(0) = 1 - 0 + e^0=2$, so the initial conditions are satisfied.

NOTE: If I were you, I would double check if I solved the correct equation. From what you wrote, everything is OK, but there's always room for some error.

Comment: The equation which we solved is correct i checked it.Thanks a lot.